# Configuration of Dynatrace in Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, dynatrace

I have an Android project, using a Gradle build configuration written in the kotlin-dsl and trying to apply Dynatrace:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("com.dynatrace.tools:android:7.2.4.1262")
  }
}

// I apply the plugin
apply(plugin = "com.dynatrace.tools.android")
```

Everything runs smoothly until I try to use the dynatrace configuration block, which is never resolved:

```
dynatrace {
    defaultConfig {
       ....
    }
}
```

This is the environment I am working with:

- Gradle: 5.1.1
- Android Gradle plugin: 3.4.1
- Dynatrace version: 7.2.4.1262

I am following [Dynatrace's own instructions](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/user-experience-management/mobile-uem/how-to-instrument-an-android-app/gradle-plugin-for-android/), and even though they don't mention how to perform the configuration with the kotlin-dsl, they have just [added support for it](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/release-notes-7-2/release-notes-android-agent-7-2/android-agent-7-2-4/).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it with the `apply` DSL and it didn't work. I got it working applying the plugin via `plugins` DSL.

Top level `build.gradle.kts`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-beta01")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31")
        classpath("com.dynatrace.tools:android:7.2.4.1262")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()  
    }
}
```

App `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    id("com.dynatrace.tools.android")
    ...
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
}

dynatrace {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I had tried that but receive an error that the plugin wasn't found. Are you pulling it from jcenter?

Comment: Put it on your app `build.gradle.kts`, not in your top level `build.gradle.kts`

Comment: I have both the dependency and plugin in my application level gradle file, not the top level one.

Comment: You should have the classpath dependency on your top level `build.gradle.kts` and the `plugins` DSL call in your app `build.gradle.kts`. I have tried many combinations here and I couldn't make it work with the classpath in my app's `build.gradle.kts`.

Comment: I have also tried that, but still receive an error (that the plugin id was not found) when trying to resolve the plugin.

Comment: I have updated my answer to having my top level and my app `build.gradle.kts`. This configuration enabled my `dynatrace` configuration block.

Comment: A cache invalidation and restart later I have everything working, after putting the dependency into the project root. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to migrate my build.gradle to KTS (with dynatrace configuration on it).
I had some problems finding the right documentation in Dynatrace website, but at the end I found it (https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/how-to-use-dynatrace/real-user-monitoring/setup-and-configuration/mobile-apps/instrument-android-app/instrumentation-via-plugin/instrumentation-via-plugin/#tabgroup-android-gradle-plugin--groovy)

The solution in my case, within the **Top level** `build.gradle.kts`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("com.dynatrace.tools.android:gradle-plugin:8.207.1.1004")
  }
}

apply(plugin = "com.dynatrace.instrumentation")
configure<com.dynatrace.tools.android.dsl.DynatraceExtension> {
    configurations {
        create("prod") {
            variantFilter("[rR]elease")
            autoStart {
                applicationId("xxx")
                beaconUrl("yyy")
            }
            userOptIn(true)
            userActions.timeout(5000)
        }
        create("debug") {
            autoStart {
                applicationId("aaa")
                beaconUrl("bbb")
            }
            userOptIn(true)
            userActions.timeout(5000)
        }
    }
}
```